# Trying to find an air conditioner unit to fit a 20x16 whole in the wall pre-existing wall unit stopped working

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a wall air conditioner in my daughter's bedroom.  It has stopped working and needs to be replaced.  The problem is I cannot find any wall units online that have a 20" width.  I'm hoping someone knows where

Comment: Consider getting it inspected and serviced rather than just replacing.  There's a good chance it just needs a regas.  What diagnosis have you done ?

Comment: The original unit was taken out last year because I was misinformed as to the ease of replacing it.  I ended up putting a window unit into the space that was too small and sealing with some 2x4's.  This year however there was bird that got into the A/C unit and built a nest I just had to remove it to get the bird out of the wall space.  I boarded up the whole for now, while I find a better solution.